# Access a Private Global variable in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Due to the nature of a project im working on, I would like to have a private variable in the Global.asax file accessible from my controllers.

Example Global.asax file

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public string SomeString { get; set; }
}
```

Example Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string theString = // How to access the SomeString from Global.asax;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is completely out of OOP principles. **private** means the scope of the variable is the class containing it **only**. You can only acess by means of a `public method`or a `public getter`

Comment: You can't do it. Private members can only be accessed from within the class where they are defined. You could do `internal`, but not `private`.

Comment: private member can't accessible from outside of class. Make it internal or public then try.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
    {
       .....
       protected string SomeString { get; set; }
       ....
    }

public class HomeController : BaseController
{
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string theString = SomeString;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to guess why will you want "Private Global". The scope of Private is only with in the class. 
if you want to make sure no other Controller can Change Value of your variable, but can read it. You can either make it Constant or Private Set.

**Public Get but Private set example.**

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public string SomeString { get; private set; }
}
```

Though if trying to restrict that only your assembly can access the variable but no other assembly (which seems unlikely as u working on MVC project). You should **try internal e.g,**

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    internal string SomeString { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
        {
            public string SomeString { get; set; }
        }


        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            public ActionResult Index()
            {

    MvcApplication mvc = new MvcApplication();
                mvc.SomeString = "Test1";
            }
        }
```

I will not suggest you do this, Its better you can create static class and static property.